# How to exit program if a file has all the numbers created

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a blank text file, in which I need to input 4 digit message_code along with single digit numbers from 0-9/A-Z at the end. So I can have 36 unique combinations for each message_code.

My code will write this random digits one by one at the end of 4 digit message_code, but when all the 36 combinations are exhausted the loop does not break, it goes into infinite mode. I want to exit the program with some message to the end user to input some other character except 0-9 or A-Z.

Code snippet:

```
import random
import string
def checkInput(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            a = input(prompt)
        except ValueError:
            print ("Sorry, I didn't understand that")
            continue
        if not a.strip():
            print ("Whitespaces encountered, please enter proper value.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return a

def addnew():
    count=int(input("How many new messagecode you want to create? "))
    for m in range(0,count):
        Mesgcode = checkInput("Enter the mesgcode")
        Rkey = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits)
        HCode = Mesgcode+Rkey
        with open('Host.txt') as f:
            z=f.read()

        def new():
            Rkey = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits)
            HCode=Mesgcode+Rkey
            return HCode

        while HCode in z:
            HCode = new()
        f1=open('Host.txt', "a")
        f1.write("New code added %s\r\n" % HCode)
        f1.close()
        m+=1

addnew()
```

The Host.txt file will look like this:

```
ABCD0
ABCD1
ABCD2
.
.
.
ABCD9
ABCDA
.
.
.
ABCDZ
```

When all the random digits are consumed, user should get a printed message `Please use different character except 0-9/A-Z, all usage exhausted`
and program should exit gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `list` or `dictionary` to save the possible value. When getting a value, remove it from your `list` or `dictionary`. Quit this program if `list` or `dictionary` is empty.

Besides: It's better to use `with open` outside the loop, otherwise you file opens and closes everytime you enter the loop.